# Two Electrons Are Moving Parallel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, magnetic-fields

Two electrons are moving parallel to each other at the same speed. How fast do they need to be moving if the magnetic force between the electrons is half the strength of the electric force between them?

Parallel to each other means in same direction. I think...
Since they are parallel to each other there is no magnetic force, correct?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: The first paragraph is a homework. The second one is a good conceptual question which is discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/532593/238167).